# Mongoose aggregate-Using group and count

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I did this query using mongoose but when I test it in Postman it shows "sending request" infinitely.What did I do wrong?

```
  userController.infectedPerAge = function(req, res, next) {
    User.aggregate([
      { $match: { estado: "Infetado" } },
      { $group: { _id: "faixaEtaria", count: { $sum: 1 } } }
    ]),
      function(err, count) {
        if (err) {
          next(err);
        } else {
          res.json(count);
        }
      };
  };
```

This is the URL I am using in Postamn http://localhost:3000/api/v1/stats/infectedPerAge

and this is my User model:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  cartaoCidadao: {
    type: String,
    require: [true, "É obrigatório indicar o cartão de cidadão"],
    Index: true,
    unique: true,
    match: /^[0-9]{8}$/,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: ["É obrigatório indicar a password"],
  },
  role: { type: String, enum: ["Admin", "Technical", "User"] },

  estado: { type: String, enum: ["Infetado", "Suspeito", "Não Infetado"] },
  sexo: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["Masculino", "Feminino"],
    require: [true, "É obrigatório indicar o sexo"],
  },
  idade: {
    type: Number,
    require: [true, "É obrigatório indicar a idade"],
  },
  faixaEtaria: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["Criança", "Adolescente", "Adulto", "Idoso"],
  },
});
```

Comment: i guess you have an error and executing `next()`. what is the next middleware you are calling?

Comment: switched to console.log(err) but it stills gives the infinit "sending request"

Comment: write this  `next(err);` to this  `res.status(400).json(err)`

Comment: did that but still inifinite "sending request..."

Comment: could you show us the url of your postman and show us more code

Comment: edited my answer with what you asked